# Joining a private network using Hamachi

Tags: hamachi

My friend sent me an invitation for private network where I have a computer B. And I can work fine from my home computer A with that network including computer B (of course).
But how can I see my home computer A when I sit at computer B? Should I send an invitation to myself and accept it at computer B?

Comment: Your Stack Overflow question will be migrated here for you. By posting this you will end up creating a duplicate.